# typescript error that property does not exist when it should

Tags: typescript

I don't understand how this message is occuring.

`Property 'message' does not exist on type '{ username: string; } | { message: string; }'.`

The relevant code (cut down):

```
// types.ts
type LoginMessage = {
  type: 'login';
  payload: { username: string };
};

type SendChatMessage = {
  type: 'send_chat_message';
  payload: { message: string };
};

export type ClientToServerMessage = LoginMessage | SendChatMessage;

// reducer.js

const { message } = action.payload; // this is the line that causes the error
// action has type ClientToServerMessage
```

Comment: It means that when the `action` is a `LoginMessage`, then there won't be a `message` property on the `payload`.

Comment: thanks @Bergi - see my answer below for what was actually causing it - I believe your point wouldn't kick in because in the switch case, typescript *knew* that action wasn't that type... which is what should happen, it just seemed weird that it wasn't!

Comment: I guess if that was the resolution, you should just delete your question, as the answer won't be helpful to anyone else. Alternatively edit the question to include the faulty `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was elsewhere... a missing `break;` in a switch case

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24422765)

Comment: @Geshode I am the author - I wasn't sure whether to delete the question or answer it myself - what would you recommend?

Comment: Deleting seems the best choice, since the problem was caused by an oversight of yours.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to narrow the `ClientToServerMessage` union type.

The example from the documentation illustrates how these can be useful by narrowing a union type.

```js
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
    return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

Any conditional branches of your code will narrow the type to `Fish` if `swim` is defined.

```js
if (isFish(pet)) {
    pet.swim(); // compiler knows that `pet` is of the `Fish` type
}
```